# Spring Boot app should only listen on Actuator's port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot asynchronous app which doesn't expose anything, since it only consume messages from a queue.
However, I want to expose actuator on a management port (8081) for this app.

Is there a way to only expose management port (8081) and not business one (8080) with Spring Boot ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `application.properties` conf bellow is enough but is it the best solution ?

```
# ----------------------------------------
# WEB PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)
server.port=8081

# ----------------------------------------
# ACTUATOR PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

# MANAGEMENT HTTP SERVER (ManagementServerProperties)
management.port=8081
```